# In CSS, do ID tags need to be attached to another tag such as 'p' or 'div'?

Tags: html, css

I understand that `#mypicture` block is creating a style for that specific ID.  What I don't understand is, in my html, why can't I just do `<id=mypicture`, why do I have to do `p id` or `img id`.

I guess more specifically my question is can an ID stand on it's own or is it always attached to something else such as a `p` tag or `div` tag?

I'm new to CSS and I'm a little confused about how to utilize the classes/id's.  My tendency is to just ignore all the `<p>`, `<div>`, etc. and just create custom classes that I can style in CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
#mypicture {
  outline-color: red; 
  border-radius: 40px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <p id="mypicture"><img src="assets/ben.jpg"></p>
    <h1>Bens's Blog</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Best Poems</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Worst Poems</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: `id` is an _attribute_, not a tag.

Comment: More specifically, `id` is one of the common HTML attributes you can attach to any element.

Comment: also, you are styling HTML elements, so it will behoove you to understand the differences, say between a <div>, a <span> and an <li> because they do different things.

Comment: One thing to remember is that HTML is a language (a markup language).  Each tag is intended to do or convey *something*.  Tags have attributes to help tags convey that *something*.  Kind of like `type="text"` and `type="password"` for the `input` tag.  One of those attributes is `id` which helps uniquely identify a given tag in a whole document. Another one is `class` which helps to group various tags (regardless of type), into a given `class-name`.  Semantically, this is basic but key concept in HTML to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes -- because an ID isn't a **tag**, it's an **attribute**.

Answer (score 3):

No an ID cannot stand on its own and
Yes it should always be attached to HTML Tags
because it is an attribute as stated.

Using a Tag in CSS like this

```
p {outline-color: red; border-radius: 40px;}
```

will give all tags < p > with outline color of red and border radius of 40px but
giving an ID in CSS like this

```
#mypicture {outline-color: red; border-radius: 40px;}
```

will only affect tags with in ID of #mypicture

Hope this gives more idea.